# How can I run an iOS voip app in the background without external signaling?

Tags: ios, objective-c, voip

I'm developing a voip app for iPad. I know there are similar questions, but none of the offered solutions have worked so far. I already know that I have to set the voip flag in the info.plist file (I used xcode for that). I have also set the "application does not run in the background" to "no" (who made up that name?!?). I also configured the socket as voip using the following two lines:

```
CFReadStreamSetProperty(readStream, kCFStreamNetworkServiceType, kCFStreamNetworkServiceTypeVoIP);
CFWriteStreamSetProperty(writeStream, kCFStreamNetworkServiceType, kCFStreamNetworkServiceTypeVoIP);
```

I read through the documentation and countless posts on SO and other forums, and there seem to be a few ways to get an app to run in the background forever. I have tried the following:

Start a long running background task, and restart the task when it fires. It was explained here on SO somewhere, but I can't find the post anymore so here is the pseudocode:

```
expirationHandler = ^{
    if (inBackground) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
        bgTask = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:expirationHandler];
    }
};

inBackground = true;
bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
bgTask = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:expirationHandler];

// Start the long-running task and return immediately.
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    // inform others to stop tasks, if you like
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"MyApplicationEntersBackground" object:self];

    inBackground = true;
    while (inBackground) {
        //send a keep alive to my server
        sleep(5);
    }
});
```

The second thing I tried was to use setKeepAliveTimeout like this:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setKeepAliveTimeout:600 handler:^{
    //send a keep alive to my server
}];
```

The first one seems to work very well (note that battery life and app-store approval are of no concern to me), but only when the application runs from xcode. When I put the app on the device and run it without debugger, the app stays alive for about 3 minutes and then it dies.

The second one seems to be how it is supposed to be, but my problem with it is that it has a minimum time of ten minutes. My server closes the connection after ten minutes of inactivity and setKeepAliveTimeout seems to be a bit inaccurate, so sometimes it is off by half a second or so (I've experienced 2 seconds one time). This means that once every ten minutes there is a chance that my session to the server is closed.
I use a protocol called XIMSS, used by the Communigate Pro server platform. Most voip apps seem to use SIP, which can send keep alive packets from the server, but that is not a option for me. So how can I make sure my app always wakes in time to send a keep alive? Is there anything that has an interval smaller than ten minutes?